# Почему сообщения не отправляются, php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Всем привет, делаю форум. Использую ajax для отправки сообщений без перезагрузки, и написал такой код:
JS:

````
```
$(document).on('load', function() {
    $('#form-bt').click(function(){
        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        var username = $("#username").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                comment: comment,
                username: username,
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert("Наконец-то всё получилось!");
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('ERROR');
            }
        })
    })
})
```
````

PHP:

````
```
 <?php
    include 'index.html';
    $connect = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=forum;charset=UTF8", 'root', 'root');
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $date = date('H:i:s');
        $query = $connect->query("INSERT INTO forum.comments (username, comment, data) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '$date')");
    }

    $comments = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM forum.comments ORDER BY data DESC");
    $comments = $comments->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($comments){
        foreach($comments as $comment){

            echo "{$comment['data']} . {$comment['username']}";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "{$comment['comment']}";
            echo "<br>";

        }
    }else{
        echo "Пока нет ни одного комментария :(";
    }
?>
```
````

HTML:

````
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
        body{
    font-family:'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input, textarea{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
p{
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: #357a6a;
}
.block-comment, .block{
    margin: 2vw 2vw 2vw 2vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.block{
    max-height: 30vw;
}
hr{
    background-color: #414b0c;
    margin: 2vw 2vw 2vw 2vw;
    height: 1%;
}
.line{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.2vw;
    margin-top: 0.5vw;
    background-color: #414b0c;
}
h2{
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; 
    margin: 2vw 2vw 2vw 2vw;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Vinnytsia City"; 
    src: url("https://fonts-online.ru/fonts/vinnytsia-city") format("truetype"); 
    font-style: normal; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-family: Vinnytsia City; /* Гарнитура шрифта */
    src: url(https://fonts-online.ru/fonts/vinnytsia-city); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
} 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
<h2>Форум</h2>

<div class="block">
    <form action="" method="POST" id="form">
        <div class="block-comment">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="r" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="10" rows="5" class="r" placeholder="Ваш комментарий" required></textarea>
            <input type="button" id="form-bt" value="отправить">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="form.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```
````

При этом, не используя submit.
Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: почему ты решил, что "сообщения не отправляются" и что ты под этим подразумеваешь?

Comment: Они должны выводится на странице и записываться в базу данных

Comment: а происходит что?

Comment: Ничего, остаётся всё также как до ввода сообщения

Comment: Включай отображение ошибок php, смотри ошибки в консоли браузера и во вкладке network и используй отладку как на фронте так и на бэке, чтобы понимать что где происходит

Comment: Вы отправляете на сервер JSON-строку, поэтому $_POST - пустой. Таким образом, либо отправляйте данные как `multipart/form-data`, либо на сервере декодируете JSON-строку из `php://input`

Comment: Отправил данные как multipart/form-data, сообщения всё равно не отправляются

Comment: var_dump($_POST) - лучшее средство отладки. В союзе с DevTools, конечно. Оставьте только эту строчку в скрипте и смотрите во вкладке Network. _"Отправил данные как multipart/form-data"_ - вы уверены, что правильно это сделали?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey var_dump?  вы из какого года пишите - из 2005-го?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А что, в 2022 её уже отменили? Старый надежный инструмент лучше новых двух. Всего одна строчка и в ответе видно, есть POST-данные или нет. Поделитесь более продвинутой технологией?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey а что, в 2022 при стиральных машинках-автоматах вы всё ещё на речке стираете вещи камнями разбивая?))  .......Применять отладку попроще. И не надо ставить миллион раз всяких выводов в output в каждом месте, где предполагается ошибка.  Тем более этих мест может быть много.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не может быть этих мест много. Человеку нужно выяснить, есть POST-данные или нет. И давайте без абстракций, расскажите про стиральную машинку будущего, как "попроще" в данном случае выяснить, пришли пост данные или нет? Я предложил конкретных два простых действия. Умираю от любопытства....

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey "Человеку нужно выяснить, есть POST-данные или нет" --- нет, ему нужно выяснить что и где не работает.........не умирайте, дышите, живите.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы на каком комментарии нить обсуждения потеряли? Вопрос изначально стоит в том, что сообщения не отправляются. По коду понятно, почему POST пустой. Я предложил два простых действия, как проверить, есть POST-данные или нет. Уверен на 100%, что вы не знаете варианта проще, иначе уже поделились бы, а абстрактные рассуждения ничем не помогут автору.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey то, что автор считает что "не отправляется" не значит что это так и есть. Для поиска причины есть хорошие средства, они описаны в дубликатах, которыми закрыт текущий, там всё можно найти (и да, я, как совсем неумный, являюсь автором ответов)........Ваше предположение о том что "вы очевидно всё увидели в коде" ложно, т.к никакой json ТС не отправляет. Там обычный объект......начали советовать какие-то бредни в виде `multipart/form-data`. Вы вообще знаете зачем оно нужно? в какие моменты лучше отсылать?.....ну и ещё урок...вот он открыл консоль и видит пустой ответ - дальше что?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137635/discussion-between-laukhin-andrey-and--).

Comment: @AlDv `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` или `$( document ).ready(function() { .. })`. По этой причине не отправляется сообщение.

Comment: Всё, сообщения отправляются, всё хорошо. Спасибо!

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, и вам тоже большое спасибо!